# How to center an image inside an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

You can check the outcome here in this [link](https://www.disabilityloversconnection.com/index.php?page=index). At the bottom of the page, on the extreme right, there is a circle with an image of a tshirt. The image is not vertically centered properly.

The css of the anchor tag is this:-

```
.dfa {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    //line-height: 10px;
}

.dfa-tshirt {
    background: #2c4762;
    color: white;
}
```

The HTML is this:-

```
<a href="https://disabilityloverstshirtbuilders.com/" class="dfa dfa-tshirt">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/100/t-shirt.png" style="width:35px; height:35; margin:auto; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;"/>
</a>
```

How can I center it? For the time being, I am using inline css for the img, which I will later remove to css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to just keep it simple, let flex handle it for you. All your margins and padding will exacerbate things when your image changes sizes or other common situations

```css
.dfa-tshirt {
    background: #2c4762;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 44px; height: 44px;
}
a img {
  width: 35px; height: 35px;
}
```

```html
    <a href="https://disabilityloverstshirtbuilders.com/" class="dfa-tshirt">
        <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/100/t-shirt.png" />
    </a>
```

---

**EDIT: Non-flex solution --**

I can't really plan for every scenario you may have, but to answer your question and support most browsers, I would also recommend just moving the actual styling to the image only:

```css
a img {
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c4762;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://disabilityloverstshirtbuilders.com/">
  <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/100/t-shirt.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: That was fantastic, but there is another issue. The circle is moved downward instead of stating with other icons side by side. Check the link

Comment: Sorry I didn’t click on the link for security reasons, also, this site has a big [link rot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) issue. Another reason I don’t click on them. If you would like to update your question with all the code necessary for future question seekers that would be great

Comment: No prob @soulshined, I have update the code with float: right and a margin:top

Comment: display: flex; support for old browsers ?

Comment: valid point @Lasantha but I can not assume what any OP specs are targeted for, and without specification I answered accordingly. For those who need browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex or https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Saswat i don't see the update on other elements or alignments. However, I updated my answer with a non-flex solution that should suffice

Comment: @soulshined - I faced lot of browser issues. can you believe some companies and clients are still using IE8 like browsers.

Answer (score 3):

**Use this:**

```
img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

```css
.dfa {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.dfa-tshirt {
    background: #2c4762;
    color: white;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://disabilityloverstshirtbuilders.com/" class="dfa dfa-tshirt">
    <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/100/t-shirt.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The images parent needs to be displayed inline-block

```
.dfa {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The inline style should just be

```
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/100/t-shirt.png" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked you site url, you can add two lines for the class as bellow.

> display: table;
>       float: right;

```
  .dfa {
        padding: 5px 5px;
        font-size: 30px;
        width: 44px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 5px 2px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: table;
        float: right;
   }
```

Img tag

```
<img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/100/t-shirt.png" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;"/>
```